# How to create cronjob using open-shift UI to call shell script file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

Can we create cronjob to make a simple shell script call without image, template information in the YAML file

For example : I have simple shell script which just prints some echo statements. How to create a cronjob to schedule it without image, jobTemplate, container etc...

Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't see any information how to create cronjob without image by kubectl as well. So OpenShift doesn't have the feature you wanted. Wondering why you wanted to create the job without image.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run

Comment: `without image`? you should spend some time on reading kubernetes basics, there is no such thing as `without image`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you can not

Q: Why do you need that?

if you want to run a simple script, create a Cronjob with a very small footprint image that includes`bash`(or the shell of your choice), like [bash](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash) or [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) (or many others) and pass your command to start your script to args

Answer (score 0):

cronjob is also run as container in openshift so you need a docker image. you can use apline or rhel universal images and can specially user shell commands against that in your job deployment file.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can not do it.

Job or Cronjob also runs the container so image is required, if you are not looking forward to creating the docker image

You can use the default **Ubuntu** (or any other alpine, busybox) image and run the command top of it by passing the argument or commands to it.

**Example**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox:1.28
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```